# Contrapositive negation quanitifier

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-writing

> Let $x, y, z$ integers. Show if $\gcd(x,y) = 1$, then $\gcd(x, yz) = \gcd(x+z, z)$

By BL, we know that $ax + by = 1, \exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that $\gcd(x + z, z) = \gcd(x, z)$ So we must show:

$\gcd(x, yz) = \gcd(x, z)$

Hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, and $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid c$.

Hint 2: Try showing that $\gcd (x,yz) \mid \gcd(x,z)$ and $\gcd(x,z) \mid \gcd (x,yz)$, at which point you conclude $\gcd (x,yz) = \gcd(x,z)$.